# Update MySQL query throwing syntax error

Tags: mysql

Trying to update a mysql employee table where the Group column if it contains the word staff it changes the contents of the column to a 4.  What am I doing wrong?

```
UPDATE employee SET Group = "4" WHERE Group LIKE "Staff";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  Quote it with backticks:

```
UPDATE employee SET `Group` = "4" WHERE `Group` LIKE "Staff";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the reserved word `GROUP`

> if it contains the word staff

and wildcard operators `%` around `LIKE` to match any instance, not just the whole string (`LIKE` without wildcards is equivalent to `=`).

```
UPDATE employee SET `Group` = "4" WHERE `Group` LIKE "%Staff%";
```